# Sinal de diferente Query

Tags: mysql, operadores, query

Tenho um problema ao apresentar a Query.

Tenho o campo `alvaraValidade` que só recebe campos Data.
Quando não coloco nada nesse campo, o campo `date` é guardado como `0000-00-00`.

```sql
$sql = "Select * From tb_trabalhador where AlvaraNumero is Not Null and AlvaraValidade is Not Null ...
```

E nessa query eu quero mostrar os que não são NULL, ou seja, os que são NULL não são mostrados. E neste caso o Campo null não funciona pois o campo é `0000-00-00`.

Ja tentei:

```sql
(...) AlvaraValidade is != '0000-00-00'
```

Mas não funciona.

Comment: Pelo jeito essa query tem varias condições, vc tem certeza que o problema é o `AlvaraValidade` ?

Answer (score 9):

Primeiro, você tem que entender que `Null`, zero e `0000-00-00` são coisas diferentes.
Além disso, tem que considerar se está usando datetime ou date.

Por exemplo, você poderia testar a query assim apenas:

```sql
Select * From tb_trabalhador where AlvaraValidade != '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
```

ou assim:

```sql
Select * From tb_trabalhador where AlvaraValidade != '0000-00-00'
```

para ter certeza de que ao menos alguma das condições está funcionando.
Depois pode testar em separado a do campo `AlvaraNumero`, e ver se funciona.

Assim que ambas estiverem em ordem, aí você testa o operador desejado, seja `and` ou `or`, conforme o resultado desejado.

Answer (score 5):

O certo seria (tem um **IS** ali que não é necessário):

```sql
... AND AlvaraValidade != '0000-00-00'
```

Ou:

```sql
... AND AlvaraValidade <> '0000-00-00'
```

Answer (score 3):

Sua *query* está errada nesse trecho:

```sql
... AND AlvaraValidade is != '0000-00-00'
```

O certo seria:

```sql
... AND AlvaraValidade = '0000-00-00'
```

Answer (score -2):

**Solução:**

---

Sinal de diferença `sql` ou `mysql` é `<>` por exemplo:

---

```sql
AlvaraValidade <> '0000-00-00'
```

ou seja use `<>` no lugar de `!=`.

Comment: Ambos os comparadores são válidos, tanto `!=` quanto `<>`.

Comment: [Documentação <> !=](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_not-equal)

Comment: @rodrigorigotti de uma olhada aqui http://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/Library/ms173258.aspx

Comment: @SilvioAndorinha olha a documentação do MySQL, em "not equal operator": https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html. Outra coisa, a query dele está com a sintaxe errada, acredito que seja esse o problema.

Comment: olha aqui @rodrigorigotti https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_not-equal

Comment: Bom, o que importa é o standard. Embora sejam aceites ambos já tive situações dentro de Stored Procedures (MySQL) onde o != tinha um comportamento estranho.
Fica para leitura: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL#Operators